# Importing XML files to SAP BW

Tags: xml, sap-bw

I have the great task of creating 300 Restricted Key Figures (RKF) in SAP BW. So far I've been doing it by hand but I found the option to Import XML files into SAP BW (in Eclipse Environment).

To get a sense of how the procedure could work, I first exported a Restricted Key Figure, deleted it in SAP BW and imported it back into SAP BW. Unfortunately, this did not work as the RKF could not be opened in SAP BW.

If anyone has experience with XML imports in SAP BW, I would appreciate an answer if this is even possible.

Comment: What do you want to import? XML is just a data format, so please describe the type of data and object you want to get from it.

Comment: @astentx Sorry, for the lated reply, but it is written in my questions. I am talking about restricted key figures.